# How do I bind to a C# wpf datagrid view cell's background?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

[image]

I have a form that decodes a message into bytes and I want to show which bits are true by highlighting a datagrid.
Eventually I plan on allowing the user to generate a message by clicking through the cells.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="messagebytegrid"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MessageBytes}"
                  CellStyle="{StaticResource MessageCell}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  SelectionUnit="Cell"
                  CanUserSortColumns="false"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                  CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                  CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                  CanUserResizeRows="False"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Binding="{Binding ByteName.Name}" IsReadOnly="True"  />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bit 1" Binding="{Binding Bit1.Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bit 2" Binding="{Binding Bit2.Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bit 3" Binding="{Binding Bit3.Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bit 4" Binding="{Binding Bit4.Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bit 5" Binding="{Binding Bit5.Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bit 6" Binding="{Binding Bit6.Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bit 7" Binding="{Binding Bit7.Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bit 8" Binding="{Binding Bit8.Name}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Each bit class has a Name string and Status boolean. I've bound the name to each cell which works fine, but how can I bind the status to either the background of individual cells or to the IsSelected attribute.

Comment: looks similar to [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66778098/1506454)

Comment: In your example I don't see how Tag is used. Do I need to add a new class so there is a 'Tag' in my data context?

Comment: Tag is a property in DataGridCell class - note `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` part of Binding. Tag is assigned in AutoGeneratingColumn event handler (DataGridCell.TagProperty)

Answer (score 0):

You could add use a `CellStyle` with a `DataTrigger` for each column:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="messagebytegrid"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MessageBytes}"
                  CellStyle="{StaticResource MessageCell}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  SelectionUnit="Cell"
                  CanUserSortColumns="false"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                  CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                  CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                  CanUserResizeRows="False"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightBrush" Color="Yellow" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Binding="{Binding ByteName.Name}" IsReadOnly="True"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bit 1" Binding="{Binding Bit1.Name}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource MessageCell}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Bit1.Status}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightBrush}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bit 2" Binding="{Binding Bit2.Name}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource MessageCell}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Bit2.Status}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightBrush}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Unfortunately, you have to define a `Style` per column since you cannot reuse a common `Style` and replace only a binding path in it in XAML.